# Cannot Update Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I am new to Ubuntu and new to this site. Whenever I try to update through the Update manager it fails and says "Package operation failed.The installation or removal of a software package failed." It's getting really annoying.

Also whenever I try to sudo apt-get upgrade, this happens at the end:

```
"Fetched 240 MB in 5min 39s (708 kB/s)                                          
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'sudo'
cups failed to preconfigure, with exit status 2
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'sudo'
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'sudo'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)"
```

Last,but not least, whenever I try to install Adobe Flash by selecting "Install missing plugins" it says it fails. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can do this (in a terminal):

```
sudo mv /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch.wrong
```

However, this will disable multiarch if you enabled it. To know exactly what happened, you should edit your question adding the output of the following command:

```
cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch*
```

This will help us figuring out what has gone wrong and how to repair the situation. Through, if you think you do not need multiarch, you can skip this last step.